# Problem about inequation with absolute value

Tags: inequality

I have this statement:

> It can be assured that | p | ≤ 2.4, if it is known that:
>
> (1) -2.7 ≤ p <2.3
>
> (2) -2.2 < p ≤ 2.6

My development was:

First, $ -2.4 \leq p \leq 2.4$

With $1)$ by itself, that can't be insured, same argument for $2)$

Now, i will use $1)$ and $2)$ together, and the intersection between this intervals are: $(-2.2, 2.3)$. So, this also does not allow me to ensure that | p | ≤ 2.4, since, there are some numbers that are outside the intersection of these two intervals, for example 2.35 is outside this interval.

But according to the guide, the correct answer must be $1), 2)$ together. And i don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You getting confused by a *strong* premise implying a *weak* conclusion.

1 and 2 together say precisely:  $p\in (-2.2,2.3) $

And you are asking to conclude $p\in [-2.4,2.4] $.

That's simply a matter of noting if $(-2.2, 2.3) \subset [-2.4,2.4] $.  And if $p $ is in a smaller subset, then we can conclude $p $ must therefore also be in the bigger superset.

Or in other words:

$-2.2 < p < 2.3\implies $

$-2.4\le -2.2 < p <2.3 \le 2.4\implies $

$-2.4\le p \le 2.4$

....

An analogy:

We can conclude $p $ is a somewhat green article of clothing if we know both

1: $p$ is a hat.

2: $p$ is precisely the color an emerald takes when viewed at noon on the summer solstice on the equator.

In your question,  1 tells you that $p <2.3$ so you can conclude $p\le 2.4$.  ($p $ is a hat so you can conclude $p $ is an article of clothing.)

And 2 tells you that $-2.2 <p $ so you can conclude $-2.4\le p $.  ($p $ is the color of emeralds so you can conclude $p $ is green.)

Together 1 and 2 tell you $-2.2<p <2.3$ so you can conclude $-2.4\le p\le 2.4$.  (Together you know $p $ is a hat the color of emeralds in a certain condition so you can conclude $p $ is a green article of clothing.)

Strong premise.  Weak result.

Comment: I had thought about it. For example, if you AFFIRM that k <10, then I can affirm that: k <15. However, my problem is that, I think, I CAN NOT affirm that it is "lesser or EQUAL" than 15, since it can take the value 15 and that contradicts the initial statement of k <10.

Comment: However, I think I understand the point. A number k can be between: 10 < k <100, and at the same time, I with that i can affirm that: -10000 <k <100000, regardless of whether there are intermediate values, this is still true, this is what I understood.

Comment: The key word is "less than OR equal" is the "OR".  If $5 < 16$ then $5 \le 16$.  $5 \le 16$ does not mean that $5 =16$.  It doesn't even mean $5$ *might* be less than $16$.  It means that exactly one of the two statements:  A) $5 < 16$ and B) $5=16$ is true.  And one of them *IS* true.  A) is true.  So A OR B is true.

Comment: We are asked to verify "Fred is green or red".  We sneak up on Fred and verify that he is a solid green.  SO we say "Yep, Fred is green so the statement is true:  Fred is green or red".  But then one of us says.  "But he *isn't* red.  So he can't be green OR RED because he isn't red".  Well... the first person is right.  Fred is completely green.  That is a subset of being green OR red.  So GREEN $\implies$ GREEN or RED.

Comment: I understand the point. Where i can get info about " strong premise implying a weak conclusion."

Answer (score 0):

$ -2.4 \leq p \leq 2.4$

$ -2.7 \leq p < 2.3$

$-2.2 < p \leq 2.6 $

Your answer is common intersection of these inequalities.

$ p \in (-2.2, 2.3)$

Answer (score 0):

The point is that if you use $1$ and $2$ together you know $-2.2 \lt p \lt 2.3$.  This does allow you to ensure $|p| \le 2.4$ because all numbers in the interval are less than $2.4$ in absolute value.  The fact that there are numbers outside the interval that also qualify does not matter at all.  If I told you that $0.1 \le p \le 0.9$ you could assure me that $|p| \le 2.4$.  You could also make a stronger statement, like $|p| \le 1$ or $|p| \le 0.9$, but that doesn't mean the one with $2.4$ is incorrect.